# What to put in an if/then statement to test whether or not a string contains a pattern

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to find out how to test whether a string contains a pattern or not.  I have as yet been unsuccessful.

I have tried using =~ but it does not seem to work.

```
IFS=;
count=0;
lspciarray=();
mylspciarrays=($(lspci -v));
for lspciarrays in "${mylspciarrays[@]}";
    do lspciarray[$count]=$lspciarrays;
    if [[ lspciarray[$count]=~^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][:][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][.][0-9a-f]* ]];
        then echo ${lspciarray[$count]};
    fi;
    ((count++));
done;
unset IFS;
```

I am expecting to get only the lines that contain the pattern ^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][:][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][.][0-9a-f]* but instead I still get the complete output from lspci -v

Comment: Please paste your code *as code* -- multiple lines, etc.

Comment: Also, note that `=~`, like every other operator, needs spaces around it.

Comment: Also, see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: Also, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: ...maybe make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here?

Comment: `IFS=` is **absolutely not** a substitute for correct quoting. `s='*'; echo $s` will still do the wrong thing, while `echo "$s"` does the right thing.

Comment: ...also, `mylspciarrays=( $(...) )` with `IFS=` will put all your results into just one element, not one element per line. If you want to read content into an array one-element-per-line, use `readarray -t mylspciarrays < <(lspci -v)` in bash 4.x or newer.

Comment: ...whereas if you just want to loop over a command's output line-by-line, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Also, it's more efficient to append to an array with `arrayname+=( "$value" )`, which doesn't require keeping track of a counter.

Comment: This question has been closed, so I can't post a full answer, but try this simple solution: `lspci -v |grep '^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][:][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][.][0-9a-f]*'`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies, I have fixed the code but have now found that everything is going into the first element in the array.  I am now working on reading the array in using readline from BashFAQ #1.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ $anything=~$anything ]]]
```

is always true, because `=~` isn't treated as an operator without spaces around it; instead, you're checking whether the result of your expansions is or is not an empty string. Because it has a constant component (the `=~`), it's always non-empty, so the operation's result is always true.

Comment: Basically he's doing a value assignment so it's always true?

Comment: Because it's in `[[ ]]`, it's not an assignment but a test; however, when you pass that syntax only one word, the test performed is a check whether the word is non-empty.